# The in_array doesn't compare my converted objects as it is supposed to

Tags: php, arrays

I'm developping a website, where if a user changes some data, it should be stored on the background, to see who did last change and what etc... . I have 1 object called Event, but the data onscreen is devided into 2 tabs (Client and Event). After the submit, I get all the fields and put the data in the object. I have this self made function to compare the values in the new boject with the values of the old object:

```
function createArrayReturnDiff($obj1, $obj2) {   
$helpArray1 = (array) $obj1; //convert object to array
$helpArray2 = (array) $obj2; //convert object to array

$help = array_diff_assoc($helpArray2, $helpArray1); //Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check

return $help;
}
```

Now this works all fine, I get an array returned with names of the field and the new value.
But here comes the tricky part. After the return of this array, I loop trough it I want to check which tab the value was on in order to give beter user feedback later. So if the value is on Cleint or Event tab. Now I made 2 arrays where I describe all the fields in each tab.

```
$tabKlant = array('Evenementfirmanaam', 'Evenementaanspreking', 'Evenementcontactpersoon', 'Evenementcontactpersoonstraat', 'Evenementcontactpersoongemeente', 'Evenementcontactpersoonland', 'Evenementcontactpersoonmail', 'Evenementcontactpersoontel', 'Evenementgeldigheidsdatum', 'Evenementfacturatiegegevens', 'Evenementfactuur_mededeling', 'Evenementbestelbon', 'Evenementreferentie');
$tabEvenement = array('Evenementstartdatum', 'Evenementeinddatum', 'Evenementnaam', 'Evenementfeestlocatie', 'Evenementcontactfeestlocatie', 'Evenementaantal', 'Evenementact_speeches_opm', 'Evenementdj', 'Evenementinleiding');
```

Now my code to check:

```
foreach ($help as $key => $value) {  
                if (in_array($key, $tabEvent)) {
                    $tab = "Event";
                } else if (in_array($key, $tabClient)) {
                    $tab = "Client";
                } else {
                    $tab = "";
                }
}
```

Now what I tried to change was Evenementfirmanaam, so the $help array contains values with key = Evenementfirmanaam and value = 'xxxx'. Everything looks like it is supposed to work. But for some reason, it can't find the value in the in_array of my foreach.

After I tried to write away data to the database. I used a mysqli_real_escape_string on the $key of my help array (firmanaam in this case) and I found out it is creating the string like: '\0Evenement\0firmanaam' . I have no idea why the \0 are added, but I have a feeling this is the reason why the in_array function won't compare my values properly. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `firmanaam` property of your `Evenement` class (which `$obj1` and `$obj2` look like to be instances of) is private, which results in the cast to array [creating special keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting):

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose
>   elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable
>   names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are
>   unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the
>   variable name; protected variables have a `'*'` prepended to the
>   variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.
>   This can result in some unexpected behaviour.

In essence, you are being punished for violating the logical design of your class: if `$firmanaam` is `private` the outside world should not have any access to its value. The cast to array does allow you to get the value but you really *should not* do this.

Since you are using `Evenement` to encapsulate and hide data members, do it all the way. If you want access to those members, provide for and use a getter. If you want to compare two instances with specific semantics, add a comparison method to the class.

Comment: I understand the upper part from what you are saying perfectly, and I changed my variables from my Class Evenement to public, but this makes no difference. Could you clearify the last part a little more?

Comment: @Dieter: Now that you changed the properties to public all those `Evenement` prefixes in `$tabKlant` etc should go as well. But (and this is also related to the last part), it sounds like you are misusing classes here. A class should be *designed*, not randomly modified to suit the tastes of the code that consumes it. Does it make sense for outside code to directly change these properties? If yes, why did you make them private in the first place? If no, is making them public a good idea?

Comment: Hey Jon, I forgot to change my 2 arrays which contained the field names for each tab, he doesn't add the objects name to the name of the key anymore when you make them public (so Evenemtfirmanaam just becomes firmanaam). I'm trying to work full OO, altough I could always use some more experience and different inside on it. But for me this was the fastest and easiest solution to compare 2 objects with each other. Thank you very much at least!!!!